# How to set backgroundColor of tabbar when the borderRadius is given to it?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

[image: Image Preview]

I want to set my `tabBar` of `borderRadius` 30 and set the `backgroundColor` of the `tabBar`, but the problem is that there is white color background in the `tabBar` even if I have set the `backgroundColor` to other color! How to resolve this?

```
tabBarOptions: {
  showIcon: true,
  showLabel: false,
  activeTintColor: '#333645',
  inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
  style: {
    backgroundColor: '#FEB6B9',
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 30,
    marginBottom: 10
  }
}
```

Comment: try to explicitly specify the transparency of your colors. two first characters of color hex are transparency. Like `#FFFEB6B9`

Comment: it didnt work!! still shows white background color as you can see in the above description

Comment: i fix this by setting the main view backgrouncColor !

Comment: which main view did you mean? the main view containing the tabbar?

Comment: no i change the app background color from android\app\src\main\res\values

Answer (score 4):

"position:'absolute'" Did the trick for me:

```
tabBar: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    borderTopWidth: 0, 
    elevation: 4,
    backgroundColor: '#FBFBFB',
    shadowRadius: 20,
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    position:'absolute'
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found a very easy way to fix this issue. You can put your Router in a view and set the view's background colour.

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1}}>
 <Router/>
</View>
```

Comment: A much better solution!!!!! Because using `position: absolute` causes screens to sit behind the tabBar and not considering `SafeArea` etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found another workaround to remove the whitespace so it can be used for both ios and android

```
const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

    const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
        HomeScreenStack,

        },
        {
            tabBarOptions: {
                style:{
                  borderRadius:50,
                  backgroundColor:"tomato",
                  position:'absolute',
                  bottom: 10,
                  padding:10,
                  width: DEVICE_WIDTH -30,
                  left:15,
                  right:15,
                  height: 54,
                  alignItems:'center',
               }
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are encompassing the bottom navigator inside a stack navigator, then you can use cardStyle of Stack Navigator`s screenOptions

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{  cardStyle: {backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'} }} >....
```